# Find the side of a cube having a vertex is on a flat surface and three vertices at distances 2,3,4 of the surface

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Will positions a cube so that one vertex is on a flat surface and the three vertices closest to,
but not on, the surface have distances of 2 cm, 3 cm and 4 cm to the surface. Determine the
exact length of the sides of the cube.

[image]

From "2012 Canadian Team Math Contests"

[Original Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnf9J.png)

[Link to PDF](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2012/2012CTMCTeamProblems.pdf)

I don't know how to approach this problem. So far, I've constructed triangles and solve them with the Pythagorean theorem however, it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy that you have added some considerations to your initial raw text.

Let $\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}$ be the vectors with common origin $O$ on the plane and resp. distance to the plane $2,3,4$.

Let $a$ be the length of the sides of the cube.

Let us take a natural coordinate system such that Oz is along the normal of the plane, giving coordinates:

$$\vec{u}=\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\2\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\3\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \vec{w}=\begin{pmatrix}w_1\\w_2\\4\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

Therefore:

$$\Omega:=\dfrac{1}{a}\begin{pmatrix}u_1&v_1&w_1\\u_2&v_2&w_2\\2&3&4\end{pmatrix}$$

(please note the division by the norm) is an orthogonal matrix; as such, its columns, **but as well its lines** "build" an orthonormal system. Therefore the third line of $\Omega$ has norm $1$. Writing this condition for the square of this norm, one gets:

$$\dfrac{1}{a^2}(2^2+3^2+4^2)=1$$

giving

$$a=\sqrt{29}$$

**Edit:** In fact, our reasoning relies on necessary conditions. Are we sure that such a cube exists ? Let us use for this a different method,  providing in fact a **second solution** that does not need orthogonal matrices.

Let us take Ox directed by the projection of $\vec{u}$ on the plane, i.e., such that $u_2=0$. As a consequence, we have:

$$\vec{u}=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{a^2-4}\\0\\2\end{pmatrix} \ \implies \  \vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}\tfrac{-6}{\sqrt{a^2-4}}\\v_2\\3\end{pmatrix}  \ \implies \  \vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}\tfrac{-6}{\sqrt{a^2-4}}\\a\tfrac{-\sqrt{a^2-13}}{\sqrt{a^2-4}}\\3\end{pmatrix}$$

(due to the facts that $\|\vec{u}\|^2=a^2, \ \vec{u} \perp \vec{v}$ and $\|\vec{v}\|^2=a^2$)

In a last step, verify (or place the constraint) $$\vec{u} \times \vec{v}= \pm a \vec{w}$$

which, for the third component (the only one on which there are constraints) gives (taking the case with a "+" sign):

$$a\sqrt{a^2-13}=4a$$

giving indeed $$a=\sqrt{29}$$

Comment: In fact, once you have the (horizontal) vector, you could complete it out to an "orthonormal" matrix by using Gram Schmidt.

Comment: @Calvin Lin: you mean in the second solution ? I don't see clearly where Gram Schmidt could be used.

Comment: Ah, I'm still thinking of the row vectors (and applying Gram Schmidt, or applying your favorite reflection matrix that sends $(2,3,4)\rightarrow (\sqrt{29},0,0) $) to calculate the entire matrix.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes indeed.

Answer (score 3):

**Using trigonometry -**

Please consider a cube which is on one of its edges (say edge $OA$) and now I lift the cube from the front such that the front vertex of the edge ($A$) is at height $4$ (say that happens at angle $\theta$) from the surface while the other vertex ($O$) stays on the ground.

The vertex to the left and to the right of the edge and facing me will be at equal height to the ground and so will be the vertices at the other end (say $B$ and $C$ on the front and $B', C'$, on the back, $B'B$ and $C'C$ being parallel edges to the left and right of our original edge $OA$). Now I rotate the cube to the left or to the right with $OA$ being the axis of rotation. This ensures the height of the vertex $A$ remains $4$ while $B'$ and $C'$ are now at different heights which are $2$ and $3$. Say the angle of rotation is $\phi$.

Please note at the beginning when our cube is on the ground on edge $OA$, $AB$ and $AC$ in the front and $OB'$ and $OC'$ in the back are all at $45^0$ to the ground.

Now we get $3$ equations -

$a \sin \theta = 4$

$a \cos \theta \sin (\frac{\pi}{4} + \phi) = 3$

$a \cos \theta \sin (\frac{\pi}{4} - \phi) = 2 \implies a \cos \theta \cos (\frac{\pi}{4} + \phi) = 2$

Dividing 2nd equation by 3rd equation, $\tan (\frac{\pi}{4} + \phi) = \frac{3}{2}$

So, $\sin (\frac{\pi}{4} + \phi) = \frac{3}{\sqrt 13}$

From 2nd equation $a \cos \theta = \sqrt{13}$, squaring this and the first equation and summing them gives us $a = \fbox {$\sqrt{29}$}$.

**ii) Just using Pythagoras and Similar Triangles,**

$h$ and $\sqrt{a^2-h^2}$ are the heights of vertices $B'$ and $C'$ along the cube surface (not vertical as the cube surface is tilted). Please note once you you rotate the cube, the angles are ($45^0 + \phi$) and ($45^0 - \phi$) (please note both of them add to $90^0$). So you get two similar right angled triangles made by $OB'$ and $OC'$ with the ground along the cube surface. The height on one side $h$ is the base on the other and the height on the other will hence be $a^2-h^2$.

Now the cube surface in which we have $O, B', C'$ is tilted towards the ground and hence length $h$ and $a^2-h^2$ in the plane along with two vertical perpendiculars to the ground of length $3$ and $2$ make two right angled similar triangles with same angle (as tilt of the plane towards the ground is same at each point in the plane).

So we have, $\frac{\sqrt{a^2 - 4^2}}{a} = \frac{3}{h} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-h^2}}$. Solving these, we get the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Align the cube so that the 3 vertices lie on the the x,y,z axes, and the plane is defined by its unit normal $n$.

You can now form an equation to solve in terms of the side-length of the cube $\lambda$ and the fact that $|n|=1$, since you know e.g. $\lambda e_x \cdot n = 2$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, could you explain further?

Comment: @Chris How do you know you can rotate the cube in the x-y plane such that the vertices lie on the axes?

Comment: @CalvinLin Everything was rotated - effectively the observer's perspective. Axes such that they coincide with the cube edges seems a natural coordinate system for this problem

Comment: Can you add more details then? While I agree you could get 3 vertices onto the axes (with little control over any other vertex), I don't see how that would help.

Comment: $\lambda e_x$, $\lambda e_y$, $\lambda e_z$ are then the 3 vertices of the cube and $n$ is the unit vector normal to the plane. We know $\lambda e_x \cdot n = 2$, $\lambda e_y \cdot n = 3$, $\lambda e_z \cdot n = 4$, and since $e_x \cdot n$ is the x coordinate of the unit normal (and so on for y and z), and since $|n|=1$ we get $\frac{\sqrt{2^2+3^2+4^2}}{\lambda}=1$

Answer (score 1):

(This is essentially Chris Kerridge's solution.)

Three edges of the cube meet on the plane. Choose them as  axes of the coordinate system. The unit normal $n$ of this plane has scalar products $(a,0,0)\cdot n=a n_1=3$, $an_2=2$, $an_3=4$ with the endpoints of these edges. It follows that
$a^2=a^2(n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2)=29$, so that $a=\sqrt{29}$.

Comment: The advantage of this solution compared to mine is that it is accessible without knowing what an isometry matrix is.