# Height of a cube edge from the floor

Tags: geometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

> A cube $ABCD.EFGH$ has side length $2a$ cm. Point $A$ is lifted $a$ cm from the floor, point $C$ is still on the floor, point $B$ and point $D$ are on the same height from the floor. What is the height of point $E$ from the floor?

I'm sorry for my bad English, but I try to illustrate it as follows.
[image: 1]

The left cube is the original one while the right side is the cube after we lifted the point $A$. In my mind, to find the height of point $E$ from the floor is to find the length of line $EN$. We can use Pythagorean theorem $EN^2=ME^2-MN^2$. But how to find the length of line $ME$ and $MN$?

Comment: Note the similar triangles to determine MA

Comment: If you are interested in a similar problem which in fact involves rotation such that $B$ and $D$ are not at the same height (that question has $A$ on floor while $C$ lifts), you can go through my solution and other solutions here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3880978/find-the-side-of-a-cube-having-a-vertex-is-on-a-flat-surface-and-three-vertices/3881654#3881654.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

As your pivot is point $C$ and points $B$ and $D$ are at the same height, the vertical edge AE will rotate by the same angle as the horizontal line  $CA$.

(another way to think is $\triangle CAE$ rotating by angle $\theta$ in the same original plane)

If $\angle ACA' = \theta, \angle CAA' = 90^0 - \theta$.

where $A'$ is the vertical projection of point $A$ on the original surface.

Also $\angle CAE = 90^0$.

So, $\angle E'AE = 180^0 - (\angle CAE + \angle CAA') = 180^0 - (90^0 + 90^0 - \theta) = \theta$

Now $CA' = \sqrt{CA^2 - AA'^2} = \sqrt{{(2\sqrt2a)^2} - a^2} = a \sqrt 7$

So $\cos \theta = \frac{CA'}{CA} = \frac{a\sqrt7}{2a\sqrt2} = \frac{\sqrt7}{2\sqrt2}$

Now perpendicular distance of $E$ from the original horizontal plane

$= a + 2a \cos \theta \,$ ($\triangle AE'E \sim \triangle CA'A$)

$= A'A + AE' = a + 2a \frac{\sqrt7}{2\sqrt2} = a(1 + \sqrt{\frac{7}{2}})$

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Never thought about that.

Comment: I think that this answer might have been a bit clearer if you just drew the plane that the square CAEG and triangle CAA' are on, along with making explicit mention of where you're using Pythagoras's Rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use similar triangles. Let $P$ be the point on $MN$ directly below $A$, and let $Q$ be the point of intersection of $EN$ and line $AC$. Since $\angle CAM$ is a right angle, we have that

$$\triangle CAP \sim \triangle AMP \sim \triangle EAQ$$

$CA \,$ is clearly $\, 2a \sqrt{2}\, $ so $\, PC = a\sqrt{7}\,.$ Then

$$\begin{align}
\frac{AC}{PC} &= \frac{EA}{EQ} \\
\\
EQ &= \frac{EA \cdot PC}{AC} \\
\\
&= \frac{(2a)(a\sqrt{7})}{2a\sqrt{2}} \\
\\
&= a \sqrt {\frac{7}{2}} \\
\\
&= \frac{a}{2} \sqrt{14}
\end{align}$$

and so the height of $E$ is

$$\begin{align}
EQ + QN &= \frac{a}{2} \sqrt{14} + a \\
\\
&= \boxed{ a \left( \frac{\sqrt{14}}{2} + 1 \right) }
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $p = \angle ACA'$, $q = \angle ECA$ (in the original figure), where $A,C,A'$ are the same as in Math Lover's answer.

Then $\tan p = \frac{1}{\sqrt 7}, p = \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt 7}$ and $\tan q = \frac{2}{2 \sqrt 2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, q = \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. Now using the [arctangent addition formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula):

$$p + q = \tan^{-1} \frac{1/\sqrt7 + 1/\sqrt2}{1 - (1/\sqrt7)(1/\sqrt2)} = \tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{14}-1} = \tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{2\cdot2\cdot7}+\sqrt{2\cdot7\cdot7}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7}}{13} = \frac{1}{13} \left(8 \sqrt2 + 3 \sqrt7 \right).$$

So $\sin(p+q) = EN / EC \Rightarrow EN = 2\sqrt{3}a \sin(p+q)$. Now since $\sin(\tan^{-1} x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ (draw a triangle), then we have the monstrous task of simplifying this expression:

$$\sin(p+q) = \frac{(1/13) \left(8 \sqrt2 + 3 \sqrt7 \right)}{\sqrt{(1/169)(191+48\sqrt{14})+1}}$$

and after incorporating the $1$, denesting the square root, and dividing, I can confirm that this eventually gives $EN = a(1 + \sqrt{7/2})$.